# How to assert type is a pointer to an interface in golang

Tags: go

I am asserting that the type of a pointer to a struct is implementing an interface in golang and there is something I don't understand in the code sample below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
}

func (m *MyStruct) MyFunc() {
    m.Name = "bar"
}

type MyInterface interface {
    MyFunc()
}

func main() {
    x := &MyStruct{
        Name: "foo",
    }
    var y interface{}
    y = x
    _, ok := y.(MyInterface)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Not MyInterface")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("It is MyInterface")
    }
}
```

I was expecting to do `_, ok := y.(*MyInterface)` since `y` is a pointer to `MyStruct`. Why can't I assert it is a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type assertion is used to find the type of the object contained in an interface. So, `y.(MyInterface)` works, because the object contained in the interface `y` is a `*MyStruct`, and it implements `MyInterface`. However, `*MyInterface` is not an interface, it is a pointer to an interface, so what you are asserting is whether `y` is a `*MyInterface`, not whether or not `y` implements `MyInterface`. This will only be successful if:

```
var x MyInterface
var y interface{}
y=&x
_, ok := y.(*MyInterface)
```